# Permanent network settings

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet

In my (virtual) Ubuntu server I'm using two network interfaces, cmd `ls /sys/class/net/` returns

```
eth0  eth1  lo
```

but `eth1` isn't enabled at startup and I have to manually setup, usually I'm using commands

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 10.10.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add default gw 10.10.0.100 eth1
sudo ifconfig eth1 up
```

My question is: how can I save configuration for `eth1`?

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Comment: If all else fails, you could add a startup script that runs those commands.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of the `/etc/network/interfaces` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the configuration file at `/etc/network/interfaces` or create a new file in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` called `eth1`

```
auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.10.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.10.0.100
```

[Debian Wiki - Network configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) is a great place to read and understand how to write network configurations